# PHP PDO write configuration file

Tags: php, pdo, fwrite

User interface allows for easy set up of a CMS. The user enters the host, database, username and password for their database the first time they activate the site in a web form.

I want to then write that information in the config file replacing the PHP variables that currently contain 'temp' with the users values.

```
<?php
$host = 'temp';
$database = 'temp';
$username = 'temp';
$password = 'temp';

try { 
    $fdbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $fdbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    }
catch(PDOException $fe) { 
    include('basic/create.php');
    }

?>
```

So I want to `$_POST` the values here in their respective places and then physically write them into the document. Possible?

Comment: Why don't you store the POST-variables into a database?

Comment: Because we cannot connect to the database until we have these details from the user

Answer (score 1):

I guess one standard approach would be having a template file with placeholders:

```
<?php
$host = '#HOST#';
$database = '#DB#';
$username = '#USER#';
$password = '#PASS#';
```

then loading that template using `file_get_contents()`, inserting the actual values using `str_replace()` and then writing the result into the final file using `file_put_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

you must put DB config values in another file and include them. 'basic/create.php' output form to enter config values and on form submit rewrite DB config file with user entered values

Comment: OK sounds interesting can you provide some detail